# callback function from caller to callee in swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, asynchronous, callback

I have a view controller and a class for doing the bits to call the services and get the data from server.
The ViewController code is below,

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{

override func viewDidLoad() {
let parser  = Parser()
parser.connectServer("abc URL" , ..... <gotDataFromServer> ..... )
}

func gotDataFromServer(response:String)
{
...... Do our things here .......
}    
}
```

and the parser code is below,

```
class Parser
{
func connectServer(apiURL:String,...<call back function name>...)
    {
        let manager = RequestOperationManager.sharedManager()
        manager.GET(apiURL ,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation,responseObject) ->Void in
                    .....<Call back the function which is passed in parameter> ....
            },
            failure: { (operation , error) in
               print ("error occurred")
        })
    }
}
```

Now in the above sample code i want to pass call back function "gotDataFromServer" as a parameter and when the inner function get the response from the server then i want to call this function back.
Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how you can do it using closure

```
class Parser {
    func connectServer(apiURL: String, completion: String -> Void) {
        // ... make call, get data
        // share the results via completion closure
        completion("data")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let parser = Parser()

        // Option #1
        parser.connectServer("mybackend.com/connect") {
            print("received data \($0)")
        }

        // Option #2 is the same as Option #1 but a bit longer
        parser.connectServer("mybackend.com/connect") { (data) -> Void in
            print("received data \(data)")
        }

        // Option #3 - Or if you have a separate funciton
        // be careful with retain cycle
        parser.connectServer("mybackend.com/connect", completion: gotDataFromServer)
    }

    func gotDataFromServer(response:String) {   }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for something similar option#3 but Nimble can you please explain a little bit about the retain cycle?

Comment: @neena there's no retain cycle in this particular example, but you should remember that closure captures `self` via strong reference. If Object A holds a closure as a property and the closure holds Object A via self in its closure's body - it's retain cycle. take a look at http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to achieve that. Try out following code

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, DataDelegate
{

override func viewDidLoad() {
let parser  = Parser()
parser.delegate = self
parser.connectServer("abc URL" , ..... <gotDataFromServer> ..... )
}

func gotDataFromServer(response:String)
{
...... Do our things here .......
}    
}
```

And add protocol in parser as follows

```
protocol DataDelegate {
    func gotDataFromServer(response:String)
}
class Parser
{
var delegate : DataDelegate!
func connectServer(apiURL:String,...<call back function name>...)
    {
        let manager = RequestOperationManager.sharedManager()
        manager.GET(apiURL ,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation,responseObject) ->Void in
                    delegate.gotDataFromServer("") //parameter is your data
            },
            failure: { (operation , error) in
               print ("error occurred")
        })
    }
}
```